# Unwanted text highlighting

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, highlight

I have a `TextBox` where the text is highlighted when you first start the app.
I don't want this. I have found methods to turn highlighting on, but never off.

In a previous text editor I could set `richtextbox.enabled = false;`, but in a regular `TextBox` it seems to make the `TextBox` unusable.
I've also tried `this.activeControl = null;`, but that doesn't work either.

How do I disable automatic text highlighting?

code:

```
password.enabled = false;
this.activeControl = null;
```

Answer (score 4):

If your password `TextBox` [TabIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex) property has the lowest value in that `Form`, (or it's the only control there) it will be the focused Control when the `Form` is shown.

To clear the selection, you just need to set it's [SelectionStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart) property to `0` (in `Form.Load()`, for example), to set the Caret at the beginnning of the text:

```
password.SelectionStart = 0;
```

or to the [TextLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.textlength) property value to set the Caret at the end of the text:

```
password.SelectionStart = password.TextLength;
```

If you don't want that specific `TextBox` selected, you could set its [TabStop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop) property to false:

```
password.TabStop = false;
```

This will move the focus to the next Control with a higher `TabIndex` (if there is one).
But, if you set its `TabStop` property to `false`, you can't use the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to move the focus to this control.

A `Form` can't have focus.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Winforms, use the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties of the textbox.